# An inequality concerning the solution of a Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, matrix-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an Hurwitz stable matrix (i.e. the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the left-half plane) and $Q$ be a positive semidefinite matrix ($Q\ge 0$, for short). Let $P>0$ be the solution of the following Lyapunov equation
$$
AP+PA^\top = -Q.
$$
and define the set $\mathcal{Q}:=\{Q\ge 0\,:\, P>0\}$.

> **My question.** Let $\lambda_{\max}(P)$ denote the largest eigenvalue of $P$. For any $Q\in\mathcal{Q}$, it is quite easy to see that
>   $$\tag{$\star$}\label{star}
> -2\,\mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{tr}(P^{-1}Q) \ge \frac{\mathrm{tr}(Q)}{\lambda_{\max}(P)},
> $$
>   where $\mathrm{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace operator.
>   However, does there *always* (i.e., for any choice of $A$ Hurwitz stable) exist a $Q=Q^\star\in \mathcal{Q}$ for which \eqref{star} is attained with equality, that is
>   $$
> -2\,\mathrm{tr}(A) = \frac{\mathrm{tr}(Q^\star)}{\lambda_{\max}(P^\star)},
> $$
>   with $P^\star$ being the solution of $AP^\star+P^\star A^\top = -Q^\star$?

Comment: I am surely missing something: why is $f(Q)$ not constant? Pre-multiplying both sides of Lyapunov equation with $P^{-1}$ and taking trace gives $f(Q) = -2\text{tr}(A)$?

Comment: @AbhishekHalder: Yes, $f(Q)$ is indeed constant; however the RHS of ($\star$) depends on $Q$. I will edit the OP in order to clarify this fact.

Comment: @Mahdi: could you please elaborate a little more your comment?

Comment: For every Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $\langle \lambda^{\downarrow}(A),\lambda^{\uparrow}(B) \rangle \leq tr(AB)$. So, if there exists $Q, P$ such that $tr(P^{-1}Q) = tr(Q) / \lambda_{max}(P)$, then all eigenvalues of $P$ are equal. am I missing something?

Comment: @Mahdi: It seems to me that, for two matrices $X>0$, $Y\ge 0$, we have $\mathrm{tr}(X^{-1}Y)=\mathrm{tr}(Y)/\lambda_{\max}(X)$, for any choice of $X$ when $Y=v_{\min}v_{\min}^\top$, with $v_{\min}$ being the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue of $X^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I supposed that $Q$  is invertible.